# Space bar doesn't work -- VoiceOver interfering?

Tags: macos, voiceover

The space bar on my late 2006 iMac with OS X 10.5.8 suddenly doesn't work. However, I just realized that if I have a word selected and hold down the spacebar for about half a second, the selection is read aloud.

- It works if I hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.
- Plugging in a different keyboard didn't help; it's not a hardware issue.
- I've tried rebooting.
- Under Keyboard Shortcuts, I clicked the button to restore defaults.
- "Enable access for assistive devices" is off.
- VoiceOver is off -- at least I think it is. I've turned it on and off a few times.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It's under System Preferences > Speech > Speak Selected Text When Key Is Pressed